# Are there infinitely many squarefree values of n(n+4)

Tags: number-theory

As the title says I was wondering whether there are infinitely many squarefree values of $n(n+4)$, $n \in \mathbb N$. Clearly $n \notin 2 \mathbb N$, but that is unfortunately the most I've gotten to so far. I know that questions about squarefree values of polynomials are extremely tough, but perhaps there exists a solution for this particular instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an odd number to be squareful, it needs to be divisible by the square of an odd prime.  $n$ and $n+4$ cannot share any odd factors, so one of them must be divisible by the square of an odd prime.  According to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared) $$\sum_{p\text{ prime}}{1\over p^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\mu(k)\over k}\log(\zeta(2k))=0.4522474200\dots \text{so}\\ \sum_{p\text{odd prime}}{1\over p^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\mu(k)\over k}\log(\zeta(2k))=0.2022474200\dots$$ at most $20.225\%$ of odd numbers are squareful.  The first term counts the fraction divisible by $3^2$, the second the number divisible by $5^2$, etc.  Some odds are divisible by the square of more than one odd prime, so the sum is an overcount.  Then at most $40.25\%$ of odd numbers of the form $n(n+4)$ are squareful.  Infinitely many  odd numbers of the form $n(n+4)$ must be squarefree.  Thanks to Hagen von Eitzen for the correction.

Comment: Where does this make use of the specific form $n(n+4)$ of the numbers? (E.g. $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ is never square-free)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  The idea is that $n$ can only be squareful less than $45.225\%$ of the time, same for $n+4$, so the product can only be squareful twice that, and in fact will be less.  This fails because if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 4, 4|n(n+4)$.  I believe it can be patched up, but will need to work on it.

Comment: Ah, I see - my eyes matched $0.45$ with $(9)0.45$ unconciously. - We can drop $\frac1{2^2}$ from the sum, so we end up with $0.2022472300\ldots$. Thus at most $40.45\%$ of all numbers $n(n+4)$ have an odd square factor. And $50\%$ have an even square factor. That still leaves $9.55\%$ without any square factor. That should fix it.